# fadeIn fadeOut jquery for both browsers

Tags: jquery

I think `fadeIn() fadeOut()` jquery should run on mobile browsers too. But it's not working. See [live demo](http://kldugargroup.com/dugar-gallery?device=desktop) for working in desktop browser and see [live demo](http://kldugargroup.com/dugar-gallery?device=iphone) for not working in mobile browser. So I am looking forward to know the alternative way for fadeIn and fadeOut function which supports in mobile browsers.

```
newImg.fadeIn(1500,function(){
   oldImg.fadeOut('1500');
   oldImg.remove();
   clicked = false;
});
```

---

I just changed according to the @Frank Anneveld to this:

```
newImg.fadeIn(1500, function(){
      oldImg.fadeOut('1500', function(){
         oldImg.remove();
      });
      clicked = false;
   });
```

Which is having the fadeIn effect but not effective as similar as desktop browser. Anyway, what am I doing bad practice in my first placed code is that removing old image while fadeIn new image?

Comment: Why are you passing a string to fadeOut instead of a number?

Comment: Oh! thanks for notifying me that. But I don't think that's a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Point here is that oldImg.remove() is removed, while fadeOut is running.
For documentation see: http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

Maybe this will help:

```
   newImg.fadeIn(1500, function(){

      oldImg.fadeOut('1500', function(){
         oldImg.remove();
      });

      clicked = false;
   });
```

or make a cross-fade:

```
   newImg.fadeIn(1500, function(){     
      clicked = false;
   });
   oldImg.fadeOut('1500', function(){
      oldImg.remove();
   });
```

Comment: But effect is not yet achieved like in desktop browser. you can check live demo for mobile that I've updated according to your script.

Comment: You are adding multiple times the jQuery framework :-) embed jQuery latest onces and go from the code jQuery(document).ready(function($){...});

Comment: Nope! I'm using external file for this.

Comment: maybe it is you clone a element:Note: Using .clone() has the side-effect of producing elements with duplicate id attributes, which are supposed to be unique. Where possible, it is recommended to avoid cloning elements with this attribute or using class attributes as identifiers instead.

Comment: I use and am using class selector where I need clone() thanks.